# RSA-4096 decrypt a file

Tags: encryption, rsa

Can I decrypt a RSA-4096 encryption without private-key?CryptoLocker have encrypted all my work data!

Answer (score 0):

You can't, you need the private key to decrypt the files.
Another option would be to brute force the private key. but brute forcing a RSA-4096 private key [would take millions of eons](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3044/31230).

Comment: we are talking of years for decrypt, right? there is no other way to decrypt my files?

Comment: @TheDallas We're not talking about years. We're talking about millions of eons. And yes, there's no other way to decrypt, than obtain the private key. You may have luck looking on other networks and checking maybe the CryptoLocker has a vulnerability (ie. it leaking the decryption file), but that's very unlikely.

Comment: I would to try to extrapolate the code behind the application.

Comment: @TheDallas Then you might have more luck on other networks about security, reverse engineering and such. This network is about programming, which this isn't.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @TheDallas Also, welcome to the stack exchange. If you ask a question and an answer helps you, or led you on the right path, then don't forget to accept it.